# Proof for Vandermonde's identity: ${{m+n} \choose r} = \sum_{k=0}^r {m \choose k}{n\choose {r-k}}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

There have been a number of proofs for this, such as:

[How to prove Vandermonde's Identity: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{R}{k}\binom{M}{n-k}=\binom{R+M}{n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337923/how-to-prove-vandermondes-identity-sum-k-0n-binomrk-binommn-k), and

[Vandermonde's Identity: How to find a closed formula for the given summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47868/vandermondes-identity-how-to-find-a-closed-formula-for-the-given-summation/47872#47872).

However, they involve a lot of hand-waving or "consider a K-by-K matrix.. or "Suppose a committee consists of m men and n women".
I'm looking for a good solid step-by-step proof:

The best one I've found comes from [this's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) Algebraic Proof:
[image]

where in line 1, the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) is applied.

From lines 1 to 2, it's just a factoring of exponents.

From line 2 to 3, it's an application of the binomial theorem on each factor term.

From line 3 to 4 however, I'm looking for some missing (assumed obvious) steps. They'll probably be a set of change of variables such as $\textrm{let } j=r-i$ then a new equation, then maybe another change of variables.

Can someone please provide step-by-step equations from line 3 to line 4?

Comment: the last step aims at finding the coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1+x)^{m+n}$. Try noting down what the step actually means in a notebook, you'll see that the coefficient is nothing but the term you started the question with.

Comment: I understand the last step, thank you. What i'm wondering about are the steps between the 2nd-to-the-last step and the last step. There's obviously a change of variables, but i can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple rearranging gives
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^m\begin{pmatrix}m\\i\end{pmatrix}x^i\sum_{j=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}n\\j\end{pmatrix}x^j&=\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}m\\i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n\\j\end{pmatrix}x^{i+j}.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
The trick  is to then swap the sum over $i$ and $j$ for a sum over $r=i+j$ and $i$.
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^m\begin{pmatrix}m\\i\end{pmatrix}x^i\sum_{j=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}n\\j\end{pmatrix}x^j&=\sum_{r=0}^{m+n}\,\sum_{i=0}^{\min(m, r)}\begin{pmatrix}m\\i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n\\r-i\end{pmatrix}x^{r}.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
Finally, we use that $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} = 0$ for $b>a$ to extend the sum over $i$ from $\min(m, r)$ to $r$.
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^m\begin{pmatrix}m\\i\end{pmatrix}x^i\sum_{j=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}n\\j\end{pmatrix}x^j&=\sum_{r=0}^{m+n}\,\sum_{i=0}^r\begin{pmatrix}m\\i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n\\r-i\end{pmatrix}x^{r}.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you. I can see that you made the substitution $i+j=r$ and therefore $j=r-i$. But the change from $m$ to $m+n$ and $n$ to $\min(m,r)$ is too fast for me. Can you explain this further, pls, other than "the trick is to swap the sum over $i$ and $j$ for a sum over..." But thank you very much for your answer. I feel like it's almost there....

Comment: Sure, so do you understand that $r$ ranges from 0 to $m+n$?

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it. Since $i$ goes from 0 to m, and $j$ goes from 0 to $n$, then $r$ must go from 0 to $m+n$. ( because $r= i+j$). And $i$ must go from 0 to r (because $i=r-j$. Thank you. Will accept this...

Answer (score 1):

> A step-by-step derivation:  We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(\sum_{i=0}^m\right.}&\color{blue}{\left.\binom{m}{i}x^i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}x^j\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{j}x^{i+j}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{m+n}\sum_{{i+j=r}\atop{i,j\geq 0}}\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{j}x^r\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{r=0}^{m+n}\left(\sum_{i=0}^r\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{r-i}\right)x^r}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we multiply out and collect the $x$-terms.
- In (2) we rearrange the terms by increasing powers of $x$.
- In (3) we substitute $j=r-i$ eliminating $j$ this way.

Answer (score 0):

Both linked questions have an answer expressing that the formula in your title is for all practical purposes obvious. At any rate, a proof does not require calculations unpacking the expressions appearing in this formula. Just select  $r$ people from a set of $m$ men and $n$ women.