# Double summation transition from Vandermonde's identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

I saw a proof for Vandermonde's identity:
[Proof for Vandermonde's identity: ${{m+n} \choose r} = \sum_{k=0}^r {m \choose k}{n\choose {r-k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548730/proof-for-vandermondes-identity-mn-choose-r-sum-k-0r-m-choose-k)

I'm new to working with sigmas, so I tried to understand the sigma transition they did, but when I thought I got it, I tried to implement it on a different double sigma but it did not work:

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^3i\sum_{j=0}^3j=\sum_{i=0}^3\sum_{j=0}^3(ij)=36
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
Then i did what they did by setting k=i+j, and by adding 3+3 the the outer sigma:
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=0}^6\sum_{i=0}^ki(k-i)=70
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
Is there something i'm missing here? how should you do this transition to relate i and j? Because i've seen these formulas in algorithm analysis (with variables instead of numbers so I can't calculate them) but I don't really know how to solve these problems.

Comment: Notice that $i$ is anyway bounded by 3, so the sum on $i$ must go from $0$ to $3$

Comment: For a fixed $k=i+j$, the range of $i$ is from $\max\{0,k-3\}$ to $\min\{3,k\}$.

Comment: Thank you metamorphy, your solution did worked!
But, do you know why in the link i sent, that said that i ranges from 0 to min{3,k}?